# Installing 32 bit libraries to run GIPsy software

Tags: 16.04, package-management, 64-bit, dependencies, libraries

I am new to this community so forgive me if I make any mistakes. I'm trying to run GIPsy which is a bioinformatics software for prediction of GEIs. The problem itself isn't with GIPsy but with a dependency called hmmer. The thing is... GIPsy was built to run the 32 bits version of hmmer, therefore I can't run both steps 4 and 7 of GIPsy because it depends on hmmer and my architecture is x64. Now, I read GIPsy manual and the last pages showed how to fix these problems with step 4 and 7 with the following command:

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386

The problem is that this command that should install some 32 bits libraries ends up not installing them and telling that there are some packages with unmet dependencies.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Alec

Answer (score 0):

You can install the unmet dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This should fix your missing packages.

Comment: apparently I have to install libjpeg62-turbo-dev but when I type: sudo apt-get -f install libjpeg62-turbo-dev it also prints an error.

Comment: Type only: sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: This command automatically installs the missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried only sudo apt-get -f install, but didn't work. I will contact the developer and see if he has an alternative. I did try to fix this problem, but ended up exterminating almost all of the OS's soul. Luckily I had a backup ready.